# Ansible role for installing and configuring SSH service

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, devops

This is the Ansible role that installs and configures SSH service. What do you think about it? Is there something to improve? Thanks

**defaults/main.yml**

```
---
# ssh daemon settings
sshd_listen_port: 22
sshd_address_family: any
sshd_listen_address:
  ipv4: '0.0.0.0'
  ipv6: '::'
sshd_protocol_2: 'yes'
sshd_host_key: ed25519
sshd_syslog_facility: AUTH
sshd_log_level: VERBOSE
sshd_login_gracetime: 2m
sshd_permit_root_login: 'no'
sshd_strict_modes: 'yes'
sshd_max_auth_tries: 2
sshd_max_sessions: 2
sshd_pubkey_auth: 'yes'
sshd_ignore_rhosts: 'yes'
sshd_passwd_auth: 'no'
sshd_permit_empty_passwords: 'no'
sshd_agent_forwarding: 'no'
sshd_tcp_forwarding: 'no'
sshd_gateway_ports: 'no'
sshd_x11_forwarding: 'no'
sshd_print_lastlog: 'yes'
sshd_tcp_keep_alive: 'no'
sshd_permit_user_env: 'no'
sshd_compression: 'no'
sshd_client_alive_count_max: 2
sshd_use_dns: 'no'
sshd_permit_tunnel: 'no'
sshd_allow_users: ''
sshd_allow_groups: wheel
sshd_ipv4_only: 'no'
sshd_use_pam: 'yes'

# ssh service settings
sshd_service_name: sshd
sshd_service_state: restarted
sshd_service_enabled: yes

# other sshd settings
sshd_config_user: root
sshd_config_group: root
sshd_package_name: openssh-server
```

**handlers/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Restart SSH service
  service:
    name: '{{ sshd_service_name }}'
    state: '{{ sshd_service_state }}'
    enabled: '{{ sshd_service_enabled }}'
  become: yes
```

**meta/main.yml**

```
---
galaxy_info:
  author: lester29
  description: Configure SSH service
  license: GPL-3.0-only
  min_ansible_version: '2.1'
  platforms:
    - name: ArchLinux
      versions:
        - all
    - name: Debian
      versions:
        - bookworm
    - name: Ubuntu
      versions:
        - 'jammy'
    - name: OpenBSD
      versions:
        - '7.3'
  galaxy_tags:
    - ssh
    - hardening
    - security
dependencies: []
```

**molecule/default/converge.yml**

```
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Include sshd
      include_role:
        name: sshd
```

**molecule/default/molecule.yml**

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy

driver:
  name: docker

platforms:
  - name: molecule-ubuntu
    image: lester29/ubuntu-ansible:22.04
    command: ${MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND:-""}
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw
    cgroupns_mode: host
    privileged: yes
    pre_build_image: yes

  - name: molecule-debian
    image: lester29/debian-ansible:bookworm
    command: ${MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND:-""}
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw
    cgroupns_mode: host
    privileged: yes
    pre_build_image: yes

  - name: molecule-centos
    image: lester29/centos-ansible:stream9
    command: ${MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND:-""}
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw
    cgroupns_mode: host
    privileged: yes
    pre_build_image: yes

provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    group_vars:
      all:
        sshd_service_name: '{{ "ssh" if ansible_distribution == "Debian" else "sshd" }}'

verifier:
  name: ansible
```

**molecule/default/requirements.yml**

```
---
collections:
  - community.docker
  - ansible.posix
```

**molecule/default/verify.yml**

```
---
- name: Verify
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Get sshd service status
      systemd:
        name: '{{ sshd_service_name }}'
      register: sshd_service_state

    - name: Check if sshd is running
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: sshd_service_state['status']['SubState'] == 'running'
```

**tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Include OS specific variables
  include_vars: '{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml'

- name: Install ssh server package
  package:
    name: '{{ sshd_package_name }}'
    state: present

- name: Set permissions to /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  file:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    owner: '{{ sshd_config_user }}'
    group: '{{ sshd_config_group }}'
    mode: '0600'

- name: 'Set SSH port to {{ sshd_listen_port }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'
    regexp: '^#*Port.*$'
    line: 'Port {{ sshd_listen_port }}'

- name: 'Set SSH address family to {{ sshd_address_family }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*AddressFamily.*$'
    line: 'AddressFamily {{ sshd_address_family }}'

- name: Set SSH IPv4 listen address
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*ListenAddress\s+0\.0\.0\.0$'
    line: 'ListenAddress {{ sshd_listen_address.ipv4 }}'

- name: Set SSH IPv6 listen address
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*ListenAddress\s+::$'
    line: 'ListenAddress {{ sshd_listen_address.ipv6 }}'
  when: not sshd_ipv4_only

- name: Configure SSH to use Protocol 2
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    line: 'Protocol 2'
    state: present
  when: sshd_protocol_2

- name: 'Set host key to use algorithm {{ sshd_host_key }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*HostKey\s+/etc/ssh/ssh_host_{{ sshd_host_key }}_key$'
    line: 'HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_{{ sshd_host_key }}_key'

- name: 'Set SyslogFacility to {{ sshd_syslog_facility }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*SyslogFacility.*$'
    line: 'SyslogFacility {{ sshd_syslog_facility }}'

- name: 'Set LogLevel to {{ sshd_log_level }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*LogLevel.*$'
    line: 'LogLevel {{ sshd_log_level }}'

- name: 'Set LoginGraceTime to {{ sshd_login_gracetime }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*LoginGraceTime.*$'
    line: 'LoginGraceTime {{ sshd_login_gracetime }}'

- name: 'Set PermitRootLogin to {{ sshd_permit_root_login | string }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*PermitRootLogin.*$'
    line: 'PermitRootLogin {{ sshd_permit_root_login | string }}'

- name: 'Set StrictModes to {{ sshd_strict_modes | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*StrictModes.*$'
    line: 'StrictModes {{ sshd_strict_modes | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set MaxAuthTries to {{ sshd_max_auth_tries }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*MaxAuthTries.*$'
    line: 'MaxAuthTries {{ sshd_max_auth_tries }}'

- name: 'Set MaxSessions to {{ sshd_max_sessions }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*MaxSessions.*$'
    line: 'MaxSessions {{ sshd_max_sessions }}'

- name: 'Set PubkeyAuthentication to {{ sshd_pubkey_auth | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*PubkeyAuthentication.*$'
    line: 'PubkeyAuthentication {{ sshd_pubkey_auth | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set IgnoreRhosts to {{ sshd_ignore_rhosts | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*IgnoreRhosts.*$'
    line: 'IgnoreRhosts {{ sshd_ignore_rhosts | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set PasswordAuthentication to {{ sshd_passwd_auth | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*PasswordAuthentication.*$'
    line: 'PasswordAuthentication {{ sshd_passwd_auth | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set PermitEmptyPasswords to {{ sshd_permit_empty_passwords | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*PermitEmptyPasswords.*$'
    line: 'PermitEmptyPasswords {{ sshd_permit_empty_passwords | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: Set UsePAM to yes
  when: sshd_use_pam
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*UsePAM.*$'
    line: 'UsePAM yes'

- name: 'Set AllowAgentForwarding forwarding to {{ sshd_agent_forwarding | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*AllowAgentForwarding.*$'
    line: 'AllowAgentForwarding {{ sshd_agent_forwarding | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set AllowTcpForwarding to {{ sshd_tcp_forwarding | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*AllowTcpForwarding\s+yes$'
    line: 'AllowTcpForwarding {{ sshd_tcp_forwarding | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set GatewayPorts to {{ sshd_gateway_ports | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*GatewayPorts.*$'
    line: 'GatewayPorts {{ sshd_gateway_ports | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set X11 forwarding to {{ sshd_x11_forwarding | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*X11Forwarding.*$'
    line: 'X11Forwarding {{ sshd_x11_forwarding | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set PrintLastLog to {{ sshd_print_lastlog | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*PrintLastLog.*$'
    line: 'PrintLastLog {{ sshd_print_lastlog | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set TCPKeepAlive to {{ sshd_tcp_keep_alive | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*TCPKeepAlive.*$'
    line: 'TCPKeepAlive {{ sshd_tcp_keep_alive | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set PermitUserEnvironment to {{ sshd_permit_user_env | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*PermitUserEnvironment.*$'
    line: 'PermitUserEnvironment {{ sshd_permit_user_env | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set Compression to {{ sshd_compression | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*Compression.*$'
    line: 'Compression {{ sshd_compression | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set ClientAliveCountMax to {{ sshd_client_alive_count_max }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*ClientAliveCountMax.*$'
    line: 'ClientAliveCountMax {{ sshd_client_alive_count_max }}'

- name: 'Set UseDNS to {{ sshd_use_dns | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*UseDNS.*$'
    line: 'UseDNS {{ sshd_use_dns | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set PermitTunnel to {{ sshd_permit_tunnel | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^#*PermitTunnel.*$'
    line: 'PermitTunnel {{ sshd_permit_tunnel | ternary("yes", "no", omit) }}'

- name: 'Set AllowUsers to {{ sshd_allow_users }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    line: 'AllowUsers {{ sshd_allow_users }}'
    insertafter: '^#*\s*VersionAddendum\s+none$'
    state: present
  when: sshd_allow_users

- name: 'Set AllowGroups to {{ sshd_allow_groups }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    line: 'AllowGroups {{ sshd_allow_groups }}'
    insertafter: 'AllowUsers'
    state: present
  when: sshd_allow_groups
  notify: Restart SSH service
```

**vars/Archlinux.yml**

```
---
sshd_package_name: openssh
```

**vars/Debian.yml**

```
---
sshd_service_name: ssh
sshd_package_name: openssh-server
```

**vars/OpenBSD.yml**

```
---
sshd_config_user: root
sshd_config_group: wheel
sshd_use_pam: no
```

**vars/RedHat.yml**

```
---
sshd_package_name: openssh-server
```